# How to make open CV show the next file name and the next value on thermal-image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get a temperature value from several image using the openCV by using the RGB value, by mouse clicking on the point that i want to see.

```
# Thermal-processing_v1.py

from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2

# Load images module
def loadImages():
    temp = os.listdir('.')
    temp.sort()
    gbr = []
    for i in temp:
        if(i.endswith('jpg')):
            gbr.append(i)

    return [os.path.join('.',f) for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.jpg')]

# Load images to python
filenames = loadImages()
images = []
gs = []

for file in filenames:
    gambar = cv2.imread(file)
    images.append(gambar)

# List of list
B = []
G = []
R = []
suhu = []
red = []
green = []
blue = []


# Mouse GUI   
def mouseRGB(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        colorsB = gambar[y,x,0]
        colorsG = gambar[y,x,1]
        colorsR = gambar[y,x,2]
        colors = gambar[y,x]
        R.append(colorsR)
        G.append(colorsG)
        B.append(colorsB)

# Mouse Window
cv2.namedWindow('mouseRGB')
cv2.setMouseCallback('mouseRGB',mouseRGB)

# Grayscale processing
for gray in images:
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gs.append(gray_image)

    while(1):
        cv2.imshow('mouseRGB',gray_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == 27 :
            for r in R:
                red.append(float(r))
            for g in G:
                green.append(float(g))
            for b in B:
                blue.append(float(b))
            nr = [i * 0.3 for i in red]
            ng = [j * 0.59 for j in green]
            nb = [k * 0.11 for k in blue]
            lum = nr + ng + nb
            tem = [z * 0.1502339357 for z in lum]
            break       
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    temp = sum(tem)
    suhu.append([file,temp])
    print(suhu)
# Appending data to csv
img_df = pd.DataFrame(suhu ,columns = ['Image', 'Temperature'])
img_df.to_csv('Olah_Suhu.csv')
```

Everything works fine for one image file and value, and if i click "esc" it continue to go to the next image. But the value and the file name it's still the same from the first one. And the value became the sum of the value that i click.

```
['./190530_0002T.jpg', 34.989483624529996]]
[['./190530_0002T.jpg', 34.989483624529996], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 69.97896724905999]]
[['./190530_0002T.jpg', 34.989483624529996], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 69.97896724905999], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 104.96845087358999]]
[['./190530_0002T.jpg', 34.989483624529996], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 69.97896724905999], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 104.96845087358999], ['./190530_0002T.jpg', 139.95793449812004]]
```

Comment: You iterate once over your files here: `for file in filenames`. There you fill your `images` list. Later, you just iterate over `images`, so the variable `file` most likely has the last value from the `filenames` list - is that correct? So, when iterating `images`, you might need to maintain an additional counter to access `filenames` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once you come out of the for loop where you load each image in the directory, i.e, `for file in filenames:`, the variable `file` will contain the name of the last image in the list `filenames`. So if the list `filenames` contains 3 images, let's say, `filenames = [1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg]`, the variable `file` will have the value of `3.jpg` once you have come out of the loop and this is what you are appending into the `suhu` list in the line `suhu.append([file,temp])`. That is why you are seeing the same image name. To solve this, use `enumerate` in the loop you are using to get each image to convert them to greyscale. This will give you each image and the index of the image. So replace the line `for gray in images:` with `for index, gray in enumerate(images):` and use `index` to get the corresponding file name by replacing `suhu.append([file,temp])` to `suhu.append([filenames[index], temp])`.
2. You are not clearing your `B`, `G`, `R`, `red`, `green` and `blue` lists. For each image, the values from the previous image get added to the list since you are using `.append`. You should clear the lists after you are done with one image using the `list_name.clear()` function if using Python 3.3 or higher or `del list[:]` for any version.
3. The `mouseRGB()` function will only be called on the image window `'mouseRGB'` instance created with `cv2.namedWindow('mouseRGB')` and assigned using `cv2.setMouseCallback('mouseRGB',mouseRGB)`. After the user hits `ESC` and you break from the `while(1)` loop, you call `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` which will close/destroy the `mouseRGB` window which had the call back function assigned so your `mouseRGB()` is not getting called after the first image. You only get the R, G, B values from the first image and since you were not clearing the lists, these first values were getting appended and added after each image. Don't call the `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` within the for loop and this will solve the problem. You can call it once you have read all images, after the for loop and right before you apped data to the csv.

I have modified your code with the changes I mentioned above and this works fine:

```
# Thermal-processing_v1.py

from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2

# Load images module
image_dir = '.'
def loadImages():
    temp = os.listdir(image_dir)
    temp.sort()
    gbr = []
    for i in temp:
        if(i.endswith('jpg')):
            gbr.append(i)
    return [os.path.join(image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

# Load images to python
filenames = loadImages()

images = []
gs = []

for file in filenames:
    gambar = cv2.imread(file)
    images.append(gambar)

# List of list
B = []
G = []
R = []
suhu = []
red = []
green = []
blue = []


# Mouse GUI   
def mouseRGB(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        colorsB = gambar[y,x,0]
        colorsG = gambar[y,x,1]
        colorsR = gambar[y,x,2]
        colors = gambar[y,x]
        R.append(colorsR)
        G.append(colorsG)
        B.append(colorsB)        

# Mouse Window
cv2.namedWindow('mouseRGB')
cv2.setMouseCallback('mouseRGB',mouseRGB)

# Grayscale processing
for index, gray in enumerate(images):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gs.append(gray_image)

    while(1):
        cv2.imshow('mouseRGB',gray_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == 27 :
            for r in R:
                red.append(float(r))
            for g in G:
                green.append(float(g))
            for b in B:
                blue.append(float(b))
            nr = [i * 0.3 for i in red]
            ng = [j * 0.59 for j in green]
            nb = [k * 0.11 for k in blue]
            lum = nr + ng + nb
            tem = [z * 0.1502339357 for z in lum]
            break       
    #cv2.destroyAllWindows()    
    temp = sum(tem)    
    suhu.append([filenames[index], temp])

    print(suhu)

    R.clear();
    G.clear();
    B.clear();

    red.clear();
    green.clear();
    blue.clear();

cv2.destroyAllWindows()    
# Appending data to csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.I forgot to using the same loop just as u said.